# How to exclude native dlls?

Tags: msbuild

In my build definition, I need a list of all compiled assemblies. This is trivial:

```
<CompiledAssemblies Include="$(OutDir)\MyCompany.*.dll" />
```

Now, if I need to exclude certain dlls, I would simply add an `Exclude` attribute. But I want to go one step further:

How do I exclude all **native** dlls from `CompiledAssemblies` above?

Comment: You're probably building the assemblies, so you'd be the one to know. But, a [.NET assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zst29sk2(v=vs.110).aspx) is a group of files with a manifest and usually at least one .NET module. Typically, that's all one file. However, it is sometimes convenient to bundle dependent native dlls into the assembly that depends on them. For a general solution, you'd have to list all files as candidates for exclusion, enumerate all manifests and remove referenced files from the exclusion list.

Comment: I have an obfuscation step that only works for .NET assemblies. Bundling native DLLs sounds interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The principle isn't that hard: batch on the list, figure out which dlls are native and create a new list with only those.

An easy way to check if a dll is a proper assembly is running `corflags` on it: if it returns 0, it's an assembly. Or in msbuild code (output is redierected to NUL else msbuild would display the errors in red):

```
<ItemGroup>
  <AllDlls Include="$(OutDir)\MyCompany.*.dll"/>
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="RunCorFlags">
  <Exec Command="corflags.exe %(AllDlls.Identity) &gt; NUL" IgnoreExitCode="true">
    <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" ItemName="CorFlagsErrorCode"/>
  </Exec>
</Target>
```

So now we just have to exclude those dlls for which CorFlagsErrorCode is 1. This should be easy, but atm I cannot figure out how to do it with pure msbuild since CorFlagsErrorCode will contain a list with 1 and 0, so no matter how many entries there are when batching on it, it will only run twice since batching skips duplicate items. Anyway as usual CodeTaskFactory provides a solution as well:

```
<Target Name="GetAssemblies" DependsOnTargets="RunCorFlags">
  <GetAssembliesOnly Dlls="@(AllDlls)" CorFlagsErr="@(CorFlagsErrorCode)">
    <Output TaskParameter="Assemblies" ItemName="CompiledAssemblies"/>
  </GetAssembliesOnly>
  <Message Text="CompiledAssemblies = %(CompiledAssemblies.Identity)"/>
</Target>

<UsingTask TaskName="GetAssembliesOnly" TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll" >
  <ParameterGroup>
    <Dlls Required="true" ParameterType="Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITaskItem[]"/>
    <CorFlagsErr Required="true" ParameterType="Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITaskItem[]"/>
    <Assemblies Output="true" ParameterType="Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITaskItem[]"/>
  </ParameterGroup>
  <Task>
    <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs">
      <![CDATA[
var temp = new List<ITaskItem>();
for( int i = 0 ; i < Dlls.Length ; ++i )
  if( CorFlagsErr[ i ].ItemSpec == "0" )
    temp.Add( Dlls[ i ] );
Assemblies = temp.ToArray();
      ]]>
    </Code>
  </Task>
</UsingTask>
```